# Azure Monitor datasource isnt working error "Azure Log Analytics requires access to Azure Monitor but had the following error: InternalServerError"

Tags: grafana

We are using the Azure-Monitor Datasource with Managed Identity. We are monitoring the Kubernetes with log analytics. We have given "Log Analytics Reader Role and Monitoring reader(subscription Level)". Till last Thursday it was working fine when I see today the data source is not working. Below is the permission that I have given now
[image]

Below is the error that I am facing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The latest released image has an issue, so I used the previously released image and the issue is solved.

Comment: Can you tell exactly what versions have you used?

Comment: I had the same issue with 8.5.* versions, and once i downgraded to 8.4.7 it started working again.

Comment: @pizycki i can confirm that this is fixed in 8.5.14 for sure (you won't find it in the changelog though https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#8514-2022-10-11) and hence should be fixed in 9.* versions as well.